# Querying over multiple bands at one point

Tags: postgis, point, query

I have a multiband raster in PostGIS. I can obtain the value for a specific band at a specific point with

```sql
SELECT ST_Value(rast, band, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(x, y), srid))
FROM table;
```

I have 12 bands in my raster. I would like to efficiently query the values for all 12 bands at one specific point, returned in, say, an ordered array. Is this possible? Or do I have to do the `ST_Value` query 12 times?